# NoClassDefFoundError in applet using cmd

Tags: java, jar, cmd, base64, japplet

I am trying to run an applet using the cmd. I have two jar files and when I compile the program I used the command:

```
javac -g -cp jar1.jar;jar2.jar MainClass.java
```

then I used the command:

```
appletviewer MainClass.html
```

to run the applet in browser.
When I pressed the button which included in applet I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach
e/commons/codec/binary/Base64
at MainClass.SearchApi(MainClass.java:279)
at MainClass$ButtonHandler.keyPressed(MainClass.java:172)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at   java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeybo
ardFocusManager.java:899)
...
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need same classpath while running appletviewer as well as you used while compiling.

```
appletviewer -J-classpath -Jjar1.jar;jar2.jar MainClass.html
```

Comment: When I try that command I get that error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: acc
ess denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "api.datamarket.azure.com:443" "connect,
resolve")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:366)